# how do i remove the administrator requirement for manipulating files on non-system hard drives in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, ntfs, administrator

I recently upgraded from xp 32bit to win7 ultimate 64bit.  i formatted the OS drive and installed on that, but i left my other drives alone.  Now when i get into windows 7, every time i try to add, move or delete a file on one of these secondary drives/partitions, it prompts me with a dialog that says something like this:

> You'll need to provide administrator permission to move this file.

This is a slight annoyance, but the real problem comes when other programs try to manipulate or delete files on these partitions.  When i try to do that with other programs it won't let me due to the administrator requirement; for instance i can't save a simple text file via notepad to one of these drives.

My question is how do I set up permissions on my other drives such that i don't need to grant access each time to a file operation, and so that other programs can access these drives normally as well?  I've taken ownership for the drives and set the owner to be both my account and the administrators group, and i've set up permissions to mimic the C drives permissions as much as i can (except i havent figured out how to set any special permissions the "Authenticated Users" group has on that drive).  Any tips?

**Edit:** i've also tried running these programs as administrator which doesn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Silly me, i figured it out; i needed to also add myself specifically to the permissions and grant myself full control; that fixed it all.

Comment: Good job figuring out the solution, and thank you for posting back with more information! Please make sure to mark this answer as accepted, so that other users will know that an answer has been found. Thanks!