# "You […] need to provide administrator permission" - how to fix

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, permissions

When I try to rename (or move) a folder, I get *Folder Access Denied*,
and
*You'll need to provide administrator permission to rename this
folder*.
There are three options: *Continue*, *Skip*, or *Cancel*.
See the screenshot below.

[image: 'need to provide administrator permission' - Continue]

It's not a big deal, really.
– I click *Continue*, and the folder is renamed.
But when this happens frequently, it soon gets rather annoying.

Some prerequisites :

- I am using an *administrator* account.
- I *am the owner* of the folder.
- My folder permissions are *Full control*.
- I have set User Account Control to *Never notify*.
  (Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, copy-paste
  <sup>1</sup>
  `useraccountcontrolsettings`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.)
- The folder is outside both `C:\Program Files` and
  `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

The behavior is as if the folder were in `C:\Program Files`,
for example.

I had the same problem a few years ago.
I found a link online that explained how to solve it.
If I recall correctly, it was a simple matter of changing merely *one*
of the folder properties.
Frustratingly, it seems I never bookmarked that helpful link.

###### I have to click *Continue* every time, to rename the folder. How can I avoid this?

---

### Some related questions

- [Disable "You'll need to provide administrator permission"](https://superuser.com/q/415735)
- ["You need administrator permission to make changes to this
  file"](https://superuser.com/q/1000031)
- [Permission to copy a file into the 'Program Files' folder](https://superuser.com/q/692461)
- [Can't delete folder as admin](https://superuser.com/q/757750)
- [Can't delete folder, and I am admin.
  "You need permission …"](https://superuser.com/q/204909)
- [How do I remove the administrator requirement for manipulating
  files](https://superuser.com/q/199691)

---

<sup>1</sup>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy,
and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ###### I have to click *Continue* every time, to rename the folder. How can I avoid this?

Right-click the folder, then *Properties* > *Security* > *Advanced* > *Enable inheritance* > *OK*.

[image: Solution: click 'Enable inheritance', and then OK.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

This solved it for me.
But maybe your case is different?
<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>
Does this help?
[Fix the “Failed to Enumerate Objects in the Container” Error](https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-fix-the-failed-to-enumerate-objects-in-the-container-error-on-windows-10).

Comment: You might want to change the owner of the folder. It appears the user who owns the folder might have come from another Windows machine. I say this because the machine name is in the owner, but the full string is cut off, suggesting it’s a user from not the same machine. As you found out you can rename the file, but it requires you to confirm that elevated task, which is successful since Administrators user group is in the ACL

Answer (score 0):

To take control of the folder that cannot be deleted, create a text file called delete.bat and add the following lines to it:

```
 SET DIRECTORY_NAME="C:\Locked Directory"
 TAKEOWN /f %DIRECTORY_NAME% /r /d y
 ICACLS %DIRECTORY_NAME% /grant administrators:F /t
 ICACLS %DIRECTORY_NAME% /reset /T
 PAUSE
```

You will need to **change the directory path to** match your requirements e.g. `C:\Locked` directory to `C:\directory_name_you_want_to_delete`.

<kbd>Right click</kbd> on the file `delete.bat`, select `Run As Administrator` and you should now have full control of the directory and all sub directories meaning you can do what you wish with them.

Comment: Your suggestion would make me the owner of the directory, but as I've stated in the second bullet of the prerequisites, I already *am the owner* of the directory.